# Changing CMOS battery on Dell Optiplex 280

Tags: cmos

I have an old **Dell optiplex 280** and its `cmos battery` just died. Please can someone tell me if I change its battery the bios will be lost? or only the bios settings will be lost (which are already lost as the battery is dead)?

Thanks.

Comment: You just remove it.  There should be a service manual for your computer.  You literally just remove it then replace it.  I could have sworn you said charge instead of change.

Comment: ok.. thanks.. I got the idea about replacement (remove it and put a new one). I just want to know its impact on the bios... bios lost vs only bios settings lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BIOS will be fine but the configuration will be lost, and will revert to the BIOS defaults.

If the battery is still good enough, go into the BIOS and copy down the settings before pulling it for replacement.

If (as you say) the battery is already dead then, depending on the BIOS persistence solution used by the motherboard, the settings are probably already gone (back to default); so just change the battery and configure the BIOS to your liking. :)

[More info on CMOS batteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory#CMOS_battery):